# Force re-render in react functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom

I'm trying to update ReactDom when a function is called,

```
function showMessage(message, config) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Message message={message.body} />,
    document.getElementById(config.targetElementId)
  );
}
```

In the message component,

```
export default function Message({ message }) {
  const [open, setIsOpen] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsOpen(true);
  }, [message]);
```

I'm using a useEffect to change the setIsOpen to true when the message changes. I want the component to call this useEffect every time showMessage(message, config) function is called. Now, the component is only re rendering if the message text is changed. message is a string like "Example string" . If I'm calling the function with showMessage("Example string", config) multiple times , it does not call the useEffect. Only if I make a change in the string ,  showMessage("Example stringssss", config), it re-renders. How do I  force re render each time the showMessage function  is called?

Comment: wrap message in an object: `{ message: message }`. As objects are compared using their reference, new object will always trigger `useEffect`.

Comment: you could just add a count `const [rerenderCount, setRerenderCount] = useState(0)` then add `rerenderCount` to the `useEffect` dependencies.  Now just call `setRerenderCount( (val) => (val > 100? 0 : val+1))` every time you want the rerender.

Comment: @Yousaf, in the dependencies?  wouldn't that create a new object every rerender?

Comment: `message={message.body}` ---> `message={ { message: message.body} }`

Answer (score 1):

You just add a props `trigger` is an object. So the component will always re-render

```
function showMessage(message, config) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Message message={message.body} trigger={{}} />,
    document.getElementById(config.targetElementId)
  );
}

function Message({ message, trigger })

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsOpen(true);
  }, [message, trigger]);
```